# Problem with makefile after rename variable

Tags: variables, makefile, rename, behavior

after changing the name of a variable into a makefile, its behavior changed drastically. From unsuccessful compilation to successful one.

I tried everything - different names, adding various additional conditions, but all without success.

Version of make:

```
$make --version
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

This is a source code file

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        return 0;
}
```

Original(desired) behavior makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .o

CC := gcc
LD := gcc

CFLAGS := -g

STRICT_CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror
INCLUDE_CFLAGS := 
ALL_CFLAGS := $(INCLUDE_CFLAGS) $(STRICT_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)


STRICT_LDFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror
INCLUDE_LDFLAGS := 
LDFLAGS := $(STRICT_LDFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
BINARIES := $(SOURCES:%.c=%)

.PHONY: all
all: $(BINARIES)

%: %.o
    @echo "Checking..."
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

.c.o:
    @echo "Creating object..."
    $(CC) $(ALL_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up..."
    -rm -rvf *.o $(BINARIES)
```

Compile output:

```
$make
gcc -g  -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror  -g  test.c   -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:1:14: error: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
} return 0;nt argc, char *argv[])
              ^
test.c:1:26: error: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
} return 0;nt argc, char *argv[])
                          ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Makefile after renaming variable (LDFLAGS -> T_LDFLAGS) - wrong behavior:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .o

CC := gcc
LD := gcc

CFLAGS := -g

STRICT_CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror
INCLUDE_CFLAGS := 
ALL_CFLAGS := $(INCLUDE_CFLAGS) $(STRICT_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)


STRICT_LDFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror
INCLUDE_LDFLAGS := 
T_LDFLAGS := $(STRICT_LDFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
BINARIES := $(SOURCES:%.c=%)

.PHONY: all
all: $(BINARIES)

%: %.o
    @echo "Checking..."
    $(LD) $(T_LDFLAGS) -o $@

.c.o:
    @echo "Creating object..."
    $(CC) $(ALL_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up..."
    -rm -rvf *.o $(BINARIES)
```

Compile output:

```
$make
gcc -g    test.c   -o test
```

Please someone explain to me why, after the name change, we lose flags for a strict code.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your make targets are being hit.  If you look at the output, you'll notice that `Checking...` is not printed and `Creating object...` is not printed.  So your program is being build with the default target.  This default target automatically adds `$(CFLAGS)` and `$(LDFLAGS)` to the build line.  That's why things stopped working when  you renamed `LDFLAGS`.

Also, your makefile currently is trying to create an executable for each individual .c file.

You need to change your targets as follows:

```makefile
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)
BINARY := myprog

.PHONY: all
all: $(BINARY)

$(BINARY): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Checking..."
    $(LD) $(T_LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

%.o: %.c
    @echo "Creating object..."
    $(CC) $(ALL_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

The `OBJECTS` variable will contain a list of .o files that correspond to each .c file.  This will be the dependency list for the binary and the list of objects to link.  The target for object files says to create a .o file for each .c file.

Comment: Wow, 10x dbush... thank you very much for the help, obviously I have a lot to learn. But just such issues help us - after 5-6 hours resarch and experiments failed to solve the problem but learned much more!

Comment: The line `$(BINARIES) : $(BINARIES).o` is wrong, unless you have exactly one source file in your directory.  As soon as you have more than one, this will break badly.

Comment: @MadScientist you're right! Do you have any idea what the problem is and how can it be solved? 10x in advance!

Comment: The problem is: if `BINARIES` contains `foo bar` then the above line expands to `foo bar : foo bar.o` which is clearly not right.  You can't just add a `.o` to the end of a variable and somehow expect it to be applied to every word in that variable... it isn't.  It just gets appended to the end of whatever the value of the variable is.  Even if it DID get appended (say you rewrote it to `$(BINARIES): $(addsuffix .o,$(BINARIES))` it would still not be right: it would have each binary depend on _all_ the object files.

Comment: Before we can help you, you need to clarify: is it *really* the case that _every_ `.c` file in your directory compiles into a separate program?  That's what your statement `BINARIES := $(SOURCES:%.c=%)` says.  That's uncommon: usually a program is built from multiple source files.  The answer to this question makes a big difference as to what a reasonable solution is.

Comment: No, all sources produced one binary.

Comment: @stoyanov I've updated my answer to reflect that a single binary will be build.